# Applying seasoning to mushrooms

Tags: seasoning

So I started baking [pleurotous mushrooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleurotus) recently; they're really yummy. The recipe proposes oil with garlic, salt, and pepper to be mixed and then spread on the mushrooms with a brush. However, this is hard, as the-carefully placed-mushrooms are simply moved if I try to brush over them!

What can I do to prevent this?
Is there maybe some device that allows me to spray a seasoning on them, without clogging despite the spices inside?

Comment: And you can't hold the mushrooms with your other hand and then just wash your hand(s)?

Comment: @ViktorMellgren - yeah, seems too sensible ;)

Comment: Sounds logical, but it's really much more comfortable to use the other hand to hold the container of the seasoning to frequently dip the brush inside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to spray that mix as the pepper will clog up the sprayer, the salt may likewise cause problems. I can think of two options that may make it easier:

1. Spray on the oil with a sprayer, then apply salt and pepper. I would use my fingers to sprinkle the salt for better control, then grind fresh pepper over
2. Mix the oil and seasoning together and toss the mushrooms in it to coat. This could work if you have enough oil mix, if it's meant to be a light coating then I would use option 1.

Comment: #1 seems weird to me. I would definitely choose number #2. Same with diced potatoes, or any other veg. Either use a large bowl, or to save on dishes pile veg/shrooms in center of baking sheet. drizzle with oil, then seasoning, then gently toss using fingers and finally "carefully place" your shrooms.

Comment: @Zak option 1 is pretty much  what I do for oven-baked sweet potato wedges, either spraying or brushing the oil, because I only really want enough oil for the seasoning to stick to.  You may want more